# How to display time in hours, mins, seconds, 100ths in datatable / datagridview

Tags: c#

I am an embedded c programmer. I have used c# before but this is my first attempt at a complex, object oriented project.

I have created a datatable and linked to a datagridview for the purpose of displaying data in a windows form.

It's working well so far. The data is stored in int form and consists primarily of times since event information in 100ths of a second. (It's the front end for a race timing system). So for example 12345 means 123.45 seconds.

I would like to show this in the form 2:03.45

I know there is the option to store data in the datatable in date and time format. However I am not sure if this will do what I need...there is no date required and it doesn't seem to cover 100th of a second.

I could format a string perhaps but this seems a bit clunky so wanted to check there wasn't a better way. Also I need to be able to use the sort functionality of the datagridview to sort each column based on the shortest time. This currently works but I'm not sure it would do with strings?

Comment: Format strings are normal: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can create `TimeSpan` and then format it to whatever format you want:

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(123.45);
string label = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:ff");
```

Output:

```
02:03:27
```

So now if you want the output to be 123 to be in minutes and 45 to be seconds than

```
double smd = 123.45;
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(smd);
string label = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm") + ":" + (int) (((decimal) smd % 1) * 100);
```

Comment: Ah brilliant....timespan looks exactly what I'm after...does it do hundredths of a second?

Comment: @NickThornton **hh:mm:ss:nnnnnn** - you get it down to ticks. For personal computers, clock ticks generally refer to the main system clock, which runs at 66 MHz. This means that there are 66 million clock ticks (or cycles) per second, so yeah you can get 100th of seconds, you can get 100,000's of a second!

Comment: So there is! .ff for hundredths.

Comment: Hundredths as in not quite milliseconds...1 second divided down a 100 times rather than 1000

Comment: @NickThornton to the left of each answer is a holo tickbox (under the up/down votes), ticking an answer gives you a few points and lets every know your problem is solved. Its good etiquette here on [so] as well, good luck!

Comment: Well thanks @JeremyThompson for such a fantastic spirit. :) Its pleasure to find you here on SO. :)

Answer (score 4):

Because you cannot use standard formats you need write your formatting logic to the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` eventhandler

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
                                          DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("LapTime"))
    {
        var hundredSeconds = (int)e.Value;
        var milliseconds = (double)(hundredSeconds * 10.0);
        var timespan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
        e.Value = timespan.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff");
        // will produce 02:03.45
    }
}
```

You can "subscribe" to this event in the constructor of your Form

```
public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    RaceResults.CellFormattiing += dataGridView1_CellFormatting;
}
```

Comment: I have added this code to my forms class. However when my datagridview updates it does not trigger this event (I have added a breakpoint to be sure). Is there anything else I need to do to connect this event to my datagridview?

Comment: looks like I need something like....RaceResults.CellStateChanged += dataGridView1_CellFormatting;     but where to put it?

Comment: thats what I tried but get the following error.....No overload for 'dataGridView1_CellFormatting' matches delegate 'DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventHandler'

Comment: Why you using `CellStateChanged`? Subscribe to `CellFormatting` event

Answer (score 2):

`TimeSpan` will help you do the job.

From your description, the time should be stored as milliseconds in your database.

So just do:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(12345);
var timeStr = ts.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

You can custom date time format by changing "HH:mm:ss" to other formats. See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks everyone...really helpful

Comment: Thanks everyone...really helpful....gotta love C#...it seems as though everything you can think of is possible...and often quite easy 